# JAVA Getting data from Database Without a loop

Tags: java, oracle, cursor, fetch, resultset

I am Programming a software with JAVA and using the Oracle DB.

Normally we obtain the values from the Database using a Loop like

```
Resultset rt = (Resultset) cs.getObject(1);

while(rt.next){
    ....
}
```

But it sound is more slowly when fetch thousand of data from the database.

My question is:

In Oracle DB: I created a Procedure like this and it is the Iterating data and assign to the  cursor.

```
Ex.procedure test_pro(sysref_cursor out info) as

open info select * from user_tbl ......

end test_pro;
```

In JAVA Code: As I mentioned before I Iterate a  the `resultset` for obtain values, but the side of database, even I select the values, why should I use a loop for getting that values?

(another fact in the .net frameworks, there are using the database binding concept. So is any way in the java, binding the database procedures like .net 's, without the iterating.
)

Comment: there is no way to do that WITHOUT looping.. :-)

Comment: @Praneeth Do you mean to say your Resultset will always return only one row from DB and you don't want while here in this case since it is single row outut? Actually RESULT-SET will allow us to iterate the columns of a single row returned from the DB. If multiple rows returned then we are need of while() to iterate multiples rows.

Comment: @ Kanagavelu Sugumar.thanks your comment.I know ,but I need to know any technology for database procedure binding like vb.net.it is always connect with the database.so .net developer don't need a loop for obtain values.

Comment: Using a resultset will let you process the rows one by one, and using a `sys_refcursor` doesn't change that - you still have to iterate over that cursor. But that doesn't mean you have a trip to the database for every row; the driver will cache a number or rows with each trip. See [setFetchSize](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/java.112/e10589/resltset.htm#i1023619). So do you *think* it will be slow, or do you have a problem now?

Comment: What are you actually doing within your loop? If you are rendering stuff for the user there is nothing you can do. If you are doing processing on the data (cross referencing, summarising, calculating) then most likely you can push that processing back into the database and drastically improve performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are going to do with that data and at which frequence, the choice for a ref_cursor might be a good or a bad one. Ref_cursors are intended to give non Oracle aware programs a way to pass it data, for reporting purposes.

In you case, stick to the looping but don't forget to implement array fetching because this has a tremendous effect on the performance. The database passes blocks of rows to your jdbc buffer at the client and your code fetches rows from that buffer. By the time you hit the end of the buffer, the Jdbc layer requests the next chunk of rows from the database, eliminating lot's of network round trips. The default already fetches 10 rows at a time. For larger sets, use bigger numbers, if memory can provide the room.

See [Oracle® Database JDBC Developer's Guide and Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/apxtips.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure there will always be exactly one result, like in this case, you can even skip the if and just call rs.next() once:

For example :

```
ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT MAX (custID) FROM customer");  
resultset.next(); // exactly one result so allowed  
int max = resultset.getInt(1); // use indexed retrieval since the column has no name
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can call procedure in java.
http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-out-parameter-example/

Comment: but , when obtain a sys_refcursor. i need a loop for fetch that Object

Comment: @Praneeth there is no way to avoid the loop if you have multiple rows.If you want to mapping database to java object without manully,you have to use some framework,like ormlite.It will cast the database rows to java objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid looping. For performance reasons you need to adjust your prefetch on Statement or Resultset object (100 is a solid starting point).
Why is done this way? It's similar to reading streams - you never know how big it can be - so you read by chunk/buffer, one after another...